# head hangs or doesn't terminate on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix, head

I'm using, (uname -a says) Linux ip-x-x-x-x 2.6.21.7-2.fc8xen-ec2-v1.0 #1 SMP Tue Sep 1 10:25:30 EDT 2009 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

I've got a script, foo.sh with 100 lines of code and when I run

> head -n 5 foo.sh

the command just "hangs" until I press Ctrl-C.

> man head

doesn't give much insight.

The path to head (via which) is /usr/bin/head

I'm SSH'd into the server if that makes a difference.

My shell is /bin/bash.

A workaround to use

> sed 5q foo.sh

works great, but I'd like an answer to this question.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: what does `head --version` report? Does `head -n 5 < foo.sh` work as expected? If so, after `head -n 5 foo.sh`, does typing a few lines of random text followed by ctl-D cause the first 5 lines of your random text to be echoed?

Comment: @rici `head --version` hangs, too!  `head -n 5 < foo.sh` doesn't work.  I tried typing anyway and my characters get echoed immediately.

Comment: If `head --version` hangs (and you have no other problems, `tail` or similar programs work etc) then this is, as @rici said, almost certainly not a normal `head` but something else.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to suggest that your `head` is symlinked to `busybox`, but even busybox will work with `head -n 5 < foo.sh`. (In fact, the one I tried works with `head -n 5 foo.sh`, but maybe there are versions which don't.) Still, it seems likely that the `head` on your machine is not any standard `head`. Perhaps its an alias, or a shell function.

Small note: It's important (although not always obvious) to distinguish between a program that is "hanging" and a program that is simply waiting for user input. Yours is waiting for user input. That's different from, for example, `sleep 3600` or `for ((i=1;i<100000000;++i)); do :; done`.

Here are some things you can try:

```
$ type head
head is aliased to `echo Surprise\!'
#...

$ type head
head is a function
head () 
{ 
    echo surprise\!
}
# ...

$ type head
head is hashed (/usr/local/bin/head)
$ file /usr/local/bin/head
/usr/local/bin/head: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable

$ type head
head is hashed (/usr/local/bin/head)
$ file /usr/local/bin/head
/usr/local/bin/head: symbolic link to `/bin/busybox'
```

Comment: Ah, file head gives this information. `ip-x-x-x-x:/usr/bin# file /usr/bin/head
/usr/bin/head: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, stripped
`

Comment: @jcarpio: Gosh, your linux kernel just celebrated its ninth birthday! Did `hash head` reveal that it was using that path? Investigating oddities like this should *not* be done from a root account, by the way. If an attacker had gotten into your system and injected nasties over top of your standard utilities (or taken advantage of a badly-configured $PATH), running them as root would be playing into their hands.

Comment: well, hash head doesn't give anything.  at this point, the sed workaround seems fine.  thanks for the help!